# How do you add a guna2VScrollBar to a datagrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

I'm trying to get a guna scroll bar to a datagrid but I don't know how to apply the scrollbar to it, can someone please tell me how I can go around doing it or if it's even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
guna2VScrollBar1.BindingContainer = dataGridView1;
```

Comment: Please add more details about why this working?

Comment: I would highly recommend reading the documentation found on Guna's website under 'Helpful Resources'.